# Silencing 는 of 만나는 in rap to 만난? When is it okay to silence parts of a word without changing meaning?

Tags: pronunciation

1:47-1:48 See You Again - Produce 48 https://youtu.be/ogUI4eeHsCg?t=108
From the phrase "만나는 날"
I played it at 20% speed to see if there was any soft enunciating for the "neun" part of 만나는, but there wasn't it seems, was straight up like 만난.  When is it okay to silence parts of a word without changing meaning for singing/rapping?

EDIT: I used to hear "만는" but @topo_morto pointed out it sounds more like "만난" and I agree.

Comment: I hear a clear /man.na.nʉn/

Comment: @Taegyung Hm, I just hear two syllables. Idk why

Comment: To me, it sounds like she doesn't quite clearly enunciate the last '는', so it sounds more like  "만난~ 날"...

Comment: "만-나-는-날"에서 "나-는-날"을 빠르게 말해서 "난~날", "나(은)날"처럼 들리는 것 같은데요? 한국어가 모국어인 사람에게는 "만나는날"이 4음절로 뚜렷하게 들리지만요. 전 그냥 표준적인 한국어 발음이라고 생각해요. 그 이면의 이유나 원리를 물으시는 거라면 중고등학생 때 생활국어 시간에 배웠을 법한 거긴 한데. 아무튼 답변하기가 어렵네요. 한국어만 잔뜩 써 온 사람에게는 그냥 그렇게 들린다는 것 말고는요. 보통 사람들은 그런 세부적인 발음 원리를 전부 분석해서 알고 있지 않거든요. 질문의 취지는 좋습니다. 국문과나 국어 교육 관련.

Comment: "나는-날" of "만나는 날" is squished. So it sounds like that. I believe there's a rule for these kind of stuff but I can't quite remember it... :p

Comment: @Coconut I'm guessing 3 consecutive consonants ㄴ, but I know nothing about Korean haha. I put the phrase on Forvo and hope some native can pronounce it https://forvo.com/phrase/%EB%A7%8C%EB%82%98%EB%8A%94_%EB%82%A0/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I played this song to my Korean friend. She agreed with Taegyung's comment - that she heard '만나는'.

I then tried saying the phrase myself to her, saying something more like 만-난-ㄴ 날, 're-voicing' the last 'ㄴ' so that it sounded like 3 syllables but without 'opening my tongue' again (so that I wasn't clearly enunciating that last '는'). That's what the song sounds most like to me.

I asked my friend what she thought I'd said - and she thought I'd said '만나는 날'. I tried again once to be sure, but she was definitely happy to interpret my '만-난-ㄴ 날' as '만나는 날'.

So it seems that you're right - in this instance, being a bit lazy with clarity of enunciation seems to be forgivable! I'm not sure if there's any specific Korean language rule that is in play here, or if it's just that when people are speaking fast in any language, some less significant sounds and syllables can be 'sacrificed' a little.

Comment: Thank for this real-life example! I figure maybe the intonation of the ㄴthat replaces 는 makes native speakers recognize it, like a different hum for the "ㅡ" part vs the "ㅏ" part? What do you think?

Comment: @CreativiTimothy I think you're right, yes - perhaps just a slightly different resonance in the mouth or something for that last 'syllable'. As a Korean learner I'm used to having to pronounce things *perfectly* to avoid being misunderstood, so it's interesting to find a counterexample!

Answer (score 1):

To me, it sounds like 만나는 날, when I have a high concentration. I
believe that I want to hear as 만난날, because 만난날 does not
stimulus a lot of my pronunciation-muscles

In CreativiTimothy's comment, a man read it fast so that he put a
stress on 만. But we can find another stress on 는, because we
easily have a high tone on 는. (cf. ㅡ use the middle of the
forehead or head voice more than ㅏ)

Singer in OP omits a stress on 만, because it is suitable for a
melody.